# Are these statements about p-values correct?

Tags: p-value

I've seen the following equivalent statements about p-values:

- *"It is the probability of wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis if it is in fact true."* [1]
- *"The P value or calculated probability is the estimated probability of rejecting the null hypothesis (H0) of a study question when that hypothesis is true."* [2]

Some people I know insist these are wrong, and say these are equivalent to type I error. But the type I error is in fact determined by the significance level. Are these right or wrong?

[1] http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/hypothesis_testing.html#pvalue

[2] http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#basics/p_values.htm

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44769/understanding-p-value?rq=1) previous discussion might help.

Answer (score 5):

There are two p-values of interest. The *critical p-value*, also known as the $\alpha$-level or significance level, is decided and fixed before the study / analysis is performed. This critical p-value is in fact the probability of Type I error. Your examples are talking about the critical p-value, and I agree with those who are saying they are incorrect or at least misleading, because in common usage "the p-value" refers to the next type of p-value.

The *observed p-value*, or calculated p-value, is calculated as part of a statistical test. The observed p-value is the probability under the null hypothesis of observing data that leads to a test statistic as or more extreme than the test statistic actually observed in the experiment. The definition of "extreme" varies depending on your test, e.g. one-sided versus two-sided. The common usage of the phrase "the p-value" usually refers to the observed p-value.

We reject the null hypothesis if the observed p-value is less than or equal to the critical p-value. This is because, under the null hypothesis, the observed p-value is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Thus the probability that we reject the null when in fact the null is true is equal to the critical p-value.

**Edit**: The full section in [[1]](http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/hypothesis_testing.html#pvalue) is talking about the observed p-values, but the one line you quoted only makes sense when talking about the critical p-value. If you were to force it to be about observed p-values and be correct, it would be something like "It is the probability of *a new, identical study* wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis if you set your alpha-level equal to it." Strictly speaking, once you've done your analysis, the probability of wrongly rejecting the null hypothesis is either 0 or 1, depending on whether or not the null hypothesis is true and whether or not you rejected it!

Comment: Thanks. But [1](http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/hypothesis_testing.html#pvalue) seems to make the statement I quoted about (observed) p-values, not significance levels. Hence the confusion.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this.